# Display content on WooCommerce single products based on product categories when they have child categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to display the test div below on any product page that is in the category cat1title or cat2title. Using the hook below, which I thought was correct, I should be seeing this div on the page but I am not seeing it at all. The page displays just fine but no div. No errors in the console either. According to docs, this should still be valid with the latest version of Woo. What am I missing?

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_by_categories', 32 ,0 );
function custom_button_by_categories(){
    
    global $product;

    // Define your categories in this array (can be Ids, slugs or names)
    $product_cats = array('cat1title', 'cat2title');

    if( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
         //$demo_url = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'demo_url', true );
         echo '<div style="background: lightblue; height 1000px; width:1000px; z-index:999; position:absolute; top:0; left:0">test</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your defined product categories need to be set on the products to work with `has_term()` function… So this will not work for parent product categories which child subcategories are set for a product…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defined product categories need to be set on the products to work with `has_term()` conditional function…

So this will not work for parent product categories which child subcategories are set for a product…

To check for parent product categories too you could use this custom conditional function:

```
// Custom conditional function that handle parent product categories too
function has_product_categories( $categories, $product_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); // Initializing
    $taxonomy        = 'product_cat';
    $product_id      = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;

    if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories;
    }

    // Convert categories term names and slugs to categories term ids
    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // It is the Main category term and we set it.
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true : false;
}
```

So in your code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_by_categories', 32 ,0 );
function custom_button_by_categories(){
    global $product;

    // Define your categories in this array (can be Ids, slugs or names)
    $categories = array('cat1title', 'cat2title');

    if( has_product_categories( $categories, $product->get_id() ) ){
         //$demo_url = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'demo_url', true );
         echo '<div style="background: lightblue; height 1000px; width:1000px; z-index:999; position:absolute; top:0; left:0">test</div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Hi thanks so much and please forgive the ignorance but do I need to fill anything out from the custom conditional function that is checking for parent cats? For example do I need to set the `$parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category` such as `$parent_term_ids[cat1title] = $term->parent; ` and then set the what its subcategories are for each of the main categories which have children ?

In the woocommerce_single.... function where the categories are defined, am I defining parent cats, or the sub cats or do I need to define the parent cat followed by all sub cats?

Comment: Hi sorry I am not sure I understand how to make this work? Happy to accept answer and upvote. I am trying to use both code sections together and am still not seeing the div pop up. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user15081222 I just tested up your code and it works, the `<div>` is displayed for the products that belongs to the defined categories (or direct children categories)… I don't know how to help you more. If you remove the if statement, does the div get displayed?

Comment: it does not. I have quite literally copied and pasted the above code with no changes. I guess what I am asking, is there something that I need to change or define? such as `$parent_term_ids[cat1title] = $term->parent; ` do I need to do something like this <<<

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought so I must have some other issue that is blocking it from being shown. Just triple check in the `custom_button_by_categories()` I am defining them the way I had in my OP. Those are all the main cats and I have NOT defined the child cats. That is ok right?>

I dont need to set anything in the `has_product_categories correct?

Comment: @user15081222 Yes thats right, just on `custom_button_by_categories()`

Comment: And I dont have to define child cats, only main cats via slug. ok well then I must have something that is blocking the request somewhere so I will accept and thank you very much for your time.